# Law of brownian hitting time uniquely determined by the barrier?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

We know that the law of
$$\tau_b := \inf\{ t >0 : B_t \geq b\} ,$$
where $b>0$ and $B$ is a standard Brownian motion, is given by a certain computable density, which is uniquely determined  by $b$.

If we replace $b$ by a continuous function $b: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty]$ and redefine $\tau_b$ as
$$\tau_b := \inf\{ t >0 : B_t \geq b(t) \}$$
I would guess that $b$ also should uniquely determine the law  of $\tau_b$.

Edit: What I mean with uniquely determination is that I ask whether the implication $b_1 \neq b_2 \Rightarrow$ Law$(\tau_{b_1})$ $\neq$ Law$(\tau_{b_2})$ is true. So that ($b$ $\mapsto$ law  of $\tau_b$) is injective

I am not asking for a solution, I want to think about it by myself, but I don't know how to approach. Any hint, comment, idea or reference is appreciated.

Edit2: The question from the first edit is called the *inverse first-passage time problem for Brownian motion*. These papers [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07827)] [[2](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tvp&paperid=5438&option_lang=eng)] show indirectly that, if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are lower semicontinuous functions with
$$\exists 0< t \leq \max (T^{b_1},T^{b_2}): b_1(t) \neq b_2 (t), $$
where
$$T^{b_i} := \inf\{t> 0 : b_i(t) = -\infty \},$$
then Law$(\tau_{b_1})$ $\neq$ Law$(\tau_{b_2})$.

Comment: Girsanov's Theorem might be relevant

Comment: If $b(t) \to \infty$ very fast then $\tau_b =\infty$ a.s.. You can use Law of Iterated logarithm for BM to see this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a "bounded" to the assumptions on $b$.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Are you asking if $b_1 = b_2$ implies that $\tau_{b_1}$ is equal in law to $\tau_{b_2}$?

Comment: @#!. Somehow I read the above the wrong way. I ask whether the implication
$b_1 \neq b_2  \Rightarrow $ Law $(\tau_{b_1})$ $\neq $ Law $(\tau_{b_2})$
is true.

Comment: @Falrach Perhaps you could state this more clearly in your question... because I also misunderstood your question. (I showed that $\tau_b$ is uniquely determined by $b$... in the sense the distribution of $\tau_b$ depends only on the values of $b$.)

Comment: I guess, this is my fault then. I edited the question. Do I use the term "uniquely determine" maybe still the wrong way ?

Comment: I guess you certainly do not want $b(0) = 0$.

Comment: Why? $b(0) = 0$ won't imply $\tau_b \equiv 0$ I think.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tau^X_b$ denote hitting time of $b$ for process $X$, that is $\tau^X_b = \inf\{t: X_t = b(t)\}$ and $b$ be absolutely continuous, that is $b(t) = b_0 + \int_0^t f(s)ds$.

$
\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
$

Process
$$
X_t = B_t - \ang{B, L}_t = B_t - \ang{B, \int f(s)dB_s}_t = B_t - \int_0^tf(s)ds
$$
is a brownian motion w.r.t. measure $\mathbb{Q}_T$ defined of $\mathcal{F}_T$ such as
$$
d\mathbb{Q}_T = \mathcal{E}(L)_T\ d\mathbb{P} = \exp({L_T-\frac12\langle L\rangle_T})d\mathbb{P} = \exp\left(\int_0^T f(t)dB_t-\frac12 \int_0^Tf(t)^2dt \right) d\mathbb{P}
$$
due to Girsanov theorem. Then it follows
$$
  \mathbb{P}(\tau^B_b \leq t) 
= \mathbb{Q}_t(\tau^X_b \leq t) 
= \mathbb{Q}_t(\tau^B_{b_0} \leq t)
= \mathbb{E}\left[1_{\tau^B_{b_0} \leq t}\mathcal{E}(L)_t\right].
$$

Some rules about how $b$ influences $\tau^B_b$ might be extracted from this.

---

Correct me if I am wrong as this result seems suspicious, e.g. consider $f = 1_{(0,1)} - 1_{(1,2)}$ and $-f$.

Comment: Sorry.. I dont understand your point.. What would be your counterexample of two different function $b_1$ and $b_2$ such that $\tau^B_{b_1}$ and $\tau^B_{b_2}$ have the same law? Dont forget that we re restricting ourselves to the case of positive bounded and continuous functions.

Comment: I calculated it by myself now what you did. I always used Girsanov backwards I noticed. However I think there is a little mistake. $X$ should be $X_t = B_t + \int_0^t f (s) ds$. But unfortunately I dont know how to learn from this result.

Comment: Btw, it does not seem suspicious to me. If you change the sign as you did, the sign of the randomness in the exponential martingale changes which corresponds to the reweighting that i necessary due to mirrorin the boundary function.

Comment: @Falrach, check that $B_t = b(t) \Leftrightarrow X_t = b_0$. I thought that the last expected value would be invariant to exchanging $f \leftrightarrow -f$ but it's not a case since the indicator and the exponential martingale are dependent, right?

Comment: Your equivalence in the comment above is true, but in your calculation you do not use it. You change the measure first and make use of the fact that the hitting time has an easier form if one defines $X$ as in my comment. The way that makes use of your equivalence also works (this is what I meant by backwards) and leads to the same result if one puts the change of measure by adding $\mathcal E _t / \mathcal E_t$.

Comment: Okay, I understand your point on $f$ and $-f$ now. But yes you seem right, the expectation looks invariant under this at first sight. But it is not due to the dependency: The probabilty wrt $\mathbb P$ on the lhs changes, the mass wrt $\mathbb P$ of the indicatorfunction does not change, but wrt $\mathbb Q$ it does due to the $\mathcal E$ density.

Comment: Okay, thanks :)